# Min-width adding space to right when on an inline-block nested in an inline-block element. (IE9 only)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use a min-width on my Bootstrap buttons, but this creates a space to the right of the button when it is inside a button group. The gap is equal to the width of the button's left and right padding (30px). This only happens in the real IE9, not 10 put into IE9 mode. If I remove the min-width or padding, the gap disappears. Any ideas on what is causing this? I removed everything but the necessary styles.

http://jsfiddle.net/aber100/2dqQ6/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Button Bug</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<style>
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 44px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  background: #999;
}
.btn-group {
  display: inline-block;
  background:pink;
}
.btn-group > .btn  {
  float: left;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="btn-group">
  <a class="btn btn-default">1</a>
</div>
<div class="btn-group">
  <a class="btn btn-default">2</a>
  <a class="btn btn-default">3</a>
  <a class="btn btn-default">4</a>
</div>
<div class="btn-group">
  <a class="btn btn-default">5 That can be longer</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is caused an `inline-block`. Inline has a 4px right margin I believe it is and must be corrected with a -4px right margin to remove it. I also just changed them all to block and the space was gone. http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/2dqQ6/3/

Comment: I'm trying to remove space that has been added inside the button group. Not the natural 3px space between each group that you will get since they are inline-bock. Please view the fiddle example in IE9. You will only see a pink background when you see the bug. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

How about like this:

Add some kind of holder and add font-size: 0 to it:

```
.btn-hold { font-size: 0; }
```

And add some font-size to the button text:

```
.btn-group {
  display: inline-block;
  background:pink;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

Since your ".btn-group" is set to display: inline-block; there will be space between the element. Whit the font-size: 0; we are removing it and setting size for the inside that font-size: 0; holder will make the text pop up once again.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2dqQ6/7/)

Comment: This does not solve the problem. Please see my comments above. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I got rid of the extra space by switching the button to display: table only in IE9.

```
:root .btn-group > .btn {
   display:table \9;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aber100/6585E/3/